# Google font taking 4-5 sec to load optimize performance

Tags: optimization, fonts, pagespeed, gtmetrix

am working on the website and i font know how to remove this font or optimize it so that the page loads faster.
when i checked on GT matrix it shows that it fonts.gstatic takes a lot of time to load.
i have tried to load just popping weight 700 only in the default theme options but no effect , still it takes a lot of time do i need to put some code or use font on my server and not get it from google or what
fonts.gstatic.com is the main problem as of now and i have no idea how to get rid of it

Website is [removed].

Comment: You can consider downloading the font you want to use, and loading it locally.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply and help, but i have no idea how to do this, i mean, theme is applying default script to load google fonts and how to add fonts to the index page in wordpress, also while trying to do so, i found quite a few font folders, that were unused. anyway can you guide a few steps for this

Comment: Without understanding your code structure  have a read of this article. https://www.google.com/amp/s/themeisle.com/blog/custom-fonts-wordpress/

Comment: @Aliqua Hey thanks, i was able to do so in the website i needed it for. i have more websites need to find how to use implement it there too. the link able was pretty informative!

Answer (score 0):

If this is a WordPress site you can use [this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/host-webfonts-local/). It solved all my font issues.

Or, there´s also another plugin that works great even though it hasn´t been updated in a couple of years.

Check out [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uqvjooEL8bE) for more info about it.

Alternatively, you can preload them as well. Fonts are a resource that doesn´t change dynamically so, this is also another very efficient way to deal with fonts and its impact on page loading speed.

Comment: thanks a lot man. i have tried it and i have found that its a hit and try kind of method for my website but i wonder why common google fonts take so long to download when a user must have them in browser due to other websites he visits.